# Does SourceMonitor works on all Platforms?

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, platform, source-monitor

I am sorry if this question is too local or duplicate. I searched in google but not got any idea.

I recently heard about SourceMonitor. I have downloaded SourceMonitor3.3 and I am using it in Windows.

I have heard SourceMonitor works on only windows. So to know about it I ma asking here.

Does it works on all all OS platforms? If not is there any code analyzer that works on all platforms?

Comment: It seems silly to have a code analysis tool that is not cross-platform, but that seems to be the case for this tool!

Answer (score 0):

The only available downloads for Source Monitor are for Windows. SOURCE: [Source Monitor v3.4](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html)

Depending on what you need to analyze, [some of the tools the Static Code Analysis Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) may work for your application. We have used FxCop for production and CodeRush in testing but we are a pure Microsoft shop.